# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential does not take 2 parameters?

Tags: c#, azure, adal

I'm using ADAL in my code. One thing I want to use is to use different credentials, so I can authorize different users against Azure AD in the console program.

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential cred = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential("username", "password");
```

This is the line I use to create the user credential. I use nuget get the latest ADAL. However, this line shows error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential.UserCredential(string, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserAuthType)' has some invalid arguments

However, according to
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.usercredential.aspx

```
UserCredential(String, String)
Constructor to create credential with client id and secret
```

Anyone knows what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't encounter this error when using UserCredential, could you provide more code? The error is weird, you are newing a **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential** while the error shows **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential.UserCredential** has invalid arguments?

Comment: use UserPasswordCredential as it inherits the UserCredential.

Answer (score 29):

In [ADAL .NET v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) [`UserCredential Constructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt473752.aspx) is no longer supports the second parameter (`password`), instead you need to use [`UserPasswordCredential` class](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/c5c66c097a6499e0c646f5ed1db1d6d278683104/src/ADAL.PCL.Desktop/UserPasswordCredential.cs)

**Example**

```
var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
var authResult = context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, credentials).Result;
```